# Get function arguments for function in named package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to get the arguments of a function, where the function name is stored as a string `func_name`. Normally I would do this as `formals(func_name)` and this works fine. However, I have a particular case where `func_name` has the package name attached as well, e.g. `package::func_name`.

The problem is that calling `formals(package::func_name)` I get:

```
Error in get(fun, mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'package::func_name' of mode 'function' was not found
```

This works if I remove the `package::` bit, so the problem is clearly the presence of `package::`.

The reason I need to this is because the `formals()` command is inside a function inside an R package that I maintain, and I want to call this function from another package that I am building. Hence, I have to use the `package::func_name` syntax in the call.

Is there any way to somehow modify the `formals()` command to accept the `package::func_name` format? I guess I could also just remove the `package::` part of the string but this seems a bit hacky. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the environment representing the name space of your package, e.g.:

```r
formals('gls', envir=getNamespace('nlme'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `base::subset` is R code that evaluates to the function so `"base::subset"` is not the name of the function; thus, evaluating it provides an easy solution (although the use of `eval` tends to be discouraged).

```
func_name <- "base::subset"
formals(eval(parse(text = func_name)))
```

An alternative is to pick it apart, `get` it and then use `formals`:

```
func_name |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ":") |>
  with(get(V3, envir = asNamespace(V1), inherits = FALSE)) |>
  formals()
```